# Can a Ruby app call Java code?

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails

This is probably really simple, but all my Google results came back with JRuby, which isn't what I want to know.  I'm curious if a regular Ruby app (e.g. a Rails app or a Sinatra app) could somehow be made to reference and call a Java library that's in the classpath?  Ideally one that works on Heroku.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not directly. Java libraries run within the JVM, Ruby apps in their own VM. If you want those two to communicate, you will need to create some kind of a comms channel between them (there are various solutions, see f.e. http://code.google.com/p/activemessaging/).

Comment: Thanks, activemessaging was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

I succeeded calling my Java program like this from Rails controller:

```
system "java -cp postgresql-9.0-801.jdbc4.jar:./ Main"
```

Couple of things to note:

- I've compiled my Main class and put it in root of my rails app (and git-pushed it to heroku).
- This call blocks rails app until java program finishes execution
- It would probably work better with [delayed_job gem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/delayed-job) (I'm working on it now)

Answer (score 1):

1. http://rjb.rubyforge.org/
2. another option would be if the jar is executable and do something like 
    [execute system command](http://blog.jayfields.com/2006/06/ruby-kernel-system-exec-and-x.html) and run it in a 'session'/terminal

Answer (score 0):

You can perform the block of commands inline of ruby (jruby) file:

```
importString = <<-eos
  java -version
  ls -l
eos

exec importString
```

This OK for Mac, but Windows jruby has some limitations.